# On SAR reports, does %commit include page cache usage?

Tags: linux, performance, sar

From the `sar` manpage:

> **%commit**
>
> Percentage of memory needed for current workload in relation to the
>   total amount of memory (RAM+swap). This number may be greater than
>   100% because the kernel usually overcommits memory.

Does this include data that had to be brought into the page cache during the given time period the entry covers?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other metrics (eg. CPU utilization) which are calculated over a time interval, the values displayed by "sar -r" (among them is %commit) are instantaneous values, based on values read from /proc/meminfo file.
So %commit includes data that are in the page cache at the end of the given time period the entry covers.

Comment: This answer would get even better with  a primary source, like a documentation or source code link